# Hazelcast partition counts and thread concurrency

Tags: java, hazelcast

In the [Master Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/resources/mastering-hazelcast/) eBook under "17.4.1. Partition-aware Operations" it states:

> To execute partition-aware operations, an array of operation threads is created.
>
> A single operation thread executes operations for multiple partitions;
>
> Each partition belongs to only 1 operation thread.

Suppose I have the default number of 271 partitions on a 17-node cluster each with 16 partition threads. Distributing the partitions across the cluster, this means all partitions will have one thread associated with it and each thread will only have 1 partition (seems the optimal case to me).

Ignoring backups and near-caches, when I create an IMap instance, does this mean I can only ever have 1 concurrent put/get operation executing on every map partition across the cluster? Going further, if I attach a MapStore, does this mean I can only ever have 271 concurrent operations running against my backend database, since there is no way of making async MapStores?

My reason for asking this is that I have a highly concurrent web-application, and I recently switched the datastore to run with Hazelcast IMap in front of it. The application accepts thousands of concurrent connection and almost every single request performs at least a get operation from the distributed map. I'm seeing a lot of these errors:

`com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: No response for 20000 ms. Aborting invocation! Invocation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation{identityHash=1003806362, serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', partitionId=244, replicaIndex=0, callId=55212219, invocationTime=1462913274676 (Tue May 10 20:47:54 UTC 2016), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=10000, name=..., name=...}, partitionId=244, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=10000, target=Address[10.0.2.221]:5701, backupsExpected=0, backupsCompleted=0, connection=Connection [/10.0.2.219:5701 -> /10.0.2.221:14565], endpoint=Address[10.0.2.221]:5701, alive=true, type=MEMBER} No response has been received!  backups-expected:0 backups-completed: 0`

Could this simply be caused by the MapStore blocking the partition thread while it's trying to fetch from the database? I should also note that while it says `No response for 20000 ms`, 20s has not elapsed.

I'm running Hazelcast 3.6.2 on Java 8.

Comment: Did you change the hazelcast.operation.call.timeout.millis due to your 20s timeout instead of the usual 2x60seconds.

Answer (score 3):

> > gnoring backups and near-caches, when I create an IMap instance, does this mean I can only ever have 1 concurrent put/get operation executing on every map partition across the cluster?

Correct. So it could be that partition 25 of map a and map b, is busy processing an operation for map b and therefor an operation for map a needs to wait.

> > Going further, if I attach a MapStore, does this mean I can only ever have 271 concurrent operations running against my backend database, since there is no way of making async MapStores?

For a write through mapstore --> yes. But I'm not that familair with writebehind (async) mapstores threading model.

> > Could this simply be caused by the MapStore blocking the partition thread while it's trying to fetch from the database? I should also note that while it says No response for 20000 ms, 20s has not elapsed.

That could very well be the cause.